# Objective C - CLLocationManager find out when "Allow" or "Don't allow" is clicked

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

When doing CLLocationManager, is there a delegate method that gets called when a user clicked the "Allow" or "Don't allow" prompt that request to use Location?

I tried this but this doesn't get called after a user "Allow" or "Don't allow".

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status;
```

Also, is there a variable that will tell me what the user selected?

I tried the below, but that always returns true.

```
locationManager.locationServicesEnabled
```

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 7):

There is a delegate method for that

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        // user allowed
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter.  With this, One way could then add [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kLocationManagerUserDidEnableMonitoring object:nil];                                                           And in the Object to be notified,     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleLocationEnabled) name:kLocationManagerUserDidEnableMonitoring object:nil];

Answer (score 4):

`[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` only tells your if the location service are enabled on the device.

`[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` returns the actual status you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement `didFailWithError:` method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    if ([error domain] == kCLErrorDomain) {

        // We handle CoreLocation-related errors here
        switch ([error code]) {
        // "Don't Allow" on two successive app launches is the same as saying "never allow". The user
        // can reset this for all apps by going to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location Warnings.
        case kCLErrorDenied:

        case kCLErrorLocationUnknown:

        default:
            break;
        }

    } else {
    // We handle all non-CoreLocation errors here
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Looking at CLLocationManager's reference I've found this:

```
+ (CLAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus
```

> Return Value 
>   A value indicating whether the application is authorized
>   to use location services.
>
> Discussion The authorization status of a given application is managed
>   by the system and determined by several factors. Applications must be
>   explicitly authorized to use location services by the user and
>   location services must themselves currently be enabled for the system.
>   This authorization takes place automatically when your application
>   first attempts to use location services.

Comment: Thanks ender. But doesn't look like this method gets called when you click on the button? Looks like it only gets called when trying to find GPS failed. Also do you know of a member variable that would tell if a user has Allow or Don't Allow?

Comment: Take note since iOS 8, this statement is no longer true: "This authorization takes place automatically when your application first attempts to use location services." You need to call requestWhenInUseAuthorization() explicitly before you call startUpdatingLocation() on the CLLocationManager. And make sure you have the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in Info.plist

Answer (score 0):

`locationManager.locationServicesEnabled` indicates whether location services is available, but not necessarily mean they are allowed for your app.

Use `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()` if you need to find out the status at a point in time, or implement

`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status;`

Take note since iOS 8, the authorization request does not takes place automatically when your application first attempts to use location services. You need to call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` explicitly before you call `startUpdatingLocation()` on your `CLLocationManager` instance.

And make sure you have the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in Info.plist, depending on the type of authorization you are after. If these are missing, there are no errors, no logs, no hints, no nothing that will point you in the right direction :)