# xamarin iOS: Location Request how to find out when user clicks “Allow” or “Don't allow” is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When the app loads, user is prompted with enable location permission. I want to move to next page only when the user hits "allow" or "don't allow" on that popup.

I saw a few questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579636/objective-c-cllocationmanager-find-out-when-allow-or-dont-allow-is-clicke) but they did not help.

My code:

```
var locationManager = new CLLocationManager();
locationManager.AuthorizationChanged += (object sender, CLAuthorizationChangedEventArgs e) => 
{
   if(ee.Status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways || ee.Status ==CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied)
    {
      //Goto next page
    }
    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
    {
        locationManager.DesiredAccuracy = CLLocation.AccuracyBest;
        locationManager.DistanceFilter = CLLocationDistance.FilterNone;
        locationManager.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();
    }
}
```

AuthorizationChanged is prompted when location dialog pops up and the status is always `CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined` and unable to detect when user clicks "allow" or "don't allow".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the app loads, user is prompted with enable location permission. I want to move to next page only when the user hits "allow" or "don't allow" on that popup.

In your `ViewDidLoad` method you can do something like this:

```
// showTrackingMap is a class level var
showTrackingMap = new LocationCheck((s, ev) =>
{
    if ((ev as LocationCheck.LocationCheckEventArgs).Allowed)
        Console.WriteLine("Present Tracking Map ViewController");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Disable Tracking Map");
    showTrackingMap.Dispose();
});
```

`LocationCheck` encapsulates the location request and the `EventHandler` will trigger once the user accepts always, only in app or denies the location privacy request.

Note: The `EventHandler` will also be called if the user is given directions to go to `Setting` to change the app from previously denied to allowed (always/app in-use).

```
public class LocationCheck : NSObject, ICLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    public class LocationCheckEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public readonly bool Allowed;
        public LocationCheckEventArgs(bool Allowed)
        {
            this.Allowed = Allowed;
        }
    }

    CLLocationManager locationManager;
    EventHandler locationStatus;

    public LocationCheck(EventHandler locationStatus)
    {
        this.locationStatus = locationStatus;
        Initialize();
    }

    public LocationCheck(NSObjectFlag x) : base(x) { Initialize(); }

    public LocationCheck(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { Initialize(); }

    public LocationCheck(IntPtr handle, bool alloced) : base(handle, alloced) { Initialize(); }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        locationManager = new CLLocationManager
        {
            Delegate = this
        };
        locationManager.RequestAlwaysAuthorization();
    }

    [Export("locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:")]
    public void AuthorizationChanged(CLLocationManager manager, CLAuthorizationStatus status)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways:
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse:
                locationStatus.Invoke(locationManager, new LocationCheckEventArgs(true));
                break;
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
            case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
                locationStatus.Invoke(locationManager, new LocationCheckEventArgs(false));
                break;
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        locationStatus = null;
        locationManager.Delegate = null;
        locationManager.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I'm looking for.